# Live Data Observer On Button Click when screen rotataed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I wish to know when button clicks on fragment and update MainActivity. This code works fine, but when screen rotated due to Activity LifeCycle OnCreate called again and viewModel.nav.observe called again with new value *true*, but I wish it to be called **only** onButton click.
What I need is onClick the value will be set to *true* and then *false*, so I only know when button clicked and not on screen rotate.
Or some other way to know the button is clicked in the fragment.

How Can I achieve this?

Fragment

```
class Fragment1 : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = Fragment1()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: SharedViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        
        buttonNextF1.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.nav.value = true
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)

        var fragment1 = Fragment1.newInstance()
        navigateToFragment(fragment1)

        viewModel.nav.observe(this, {
            Log.d("DTAG", "Status: $it")
        })
    }

    private fun navigateToFragment(fragment: Fragment) {

        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()

    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    
    var nav = MutableLiveData(false)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) to achieve your goal because:

- You only want to notify the event (click button on fragment) once
- There is only one observer (MainActivity) that observe on the LiveData

**Step 1:** Create a SingleLiveEvent.kt file

```
class SingleLiveEvent<T> : MutableLiveData<T?>() {
    private val mPending = AtomicBoolean(false)

    @MainThread
    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T?>) {
        if (hasActiveObservers()) {
            Log.w(
                TAG,
                "Multiple observers registered but only one will be notified of changes."
            )
        }
        // Observe the internal MutableLiveData
        super.observe(owner, Observer { t ->
            if (mPending.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                observer.onChanged(t)
            }
        })
    }

    @MainThread
    override fun setValue(t: T?) {
        mPending.set(true)
        super.setValue(t)
    }

    /**
     * Used for cases where T is Void, to make calls cleaner.
     */
    @MainThread
    fun call() {
        value = null
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "SingleLiveEvent"
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** In SharedViewModel

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var nav = SingleLiveEvent<Boolean>()
}
```

**Step 3:** In MainActivity

```
viewModel.nav.observe(this, Observer {
    Log.d("DTAG", "Status: $it")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this solution, but [this code lab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-quality-and-states#2) says, you should post "navigation handled" event back to view model.

#### View model implementation:

```kotlin
interface MyViewModel {
    val navigationEvent: LiveData<Unit?>
    
    fun onNavigationButtonClicked()
    fun onNavigationDone()
}

class MyViewModelImpl : ViewModel(), MyViewModel {
    
    override val navigationEvent = MutableLiveData<Unit?>()

    override fun onNavigationButtonClicked() {
        navigationEvent.value = Unit
    }

    override fun onNavigationDone() {
        navigationEvent.value = null
    }
}
```

#### View model usage

```kotlin
vm.navigationEvent.observe(lifecycleOwner, { event ->
    // check event is not handled yet
    event ?: return@observe
    // make transition
    findNavController().navigate(direction)
    // notify view model navigation event is handled
    vm.onNavigationDone()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use saveStateViewMode, document [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate)